# TypeError: "worksheet" object not callable while writing on an existing workbook sheet

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, export-to-excel

I am trying to write a list into a column of an existing workbook sheet using openpyxl- in column A, from row13 onwards- and I am having this error "TypeError: “worksheet” object not callable". Here is the code I have used-

```
variable_name = ["a","b","c"]
workbook = load_workbook("file.xlsx")
ws = workbook['9. Family Assignment']
for i in range(0,len(variable_name)):
    ws(row =i+13,col = 'A').value = variable_name[i]
```

The excel file I am using
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X62EnywUWXwsv5KErbUCUqq4D-ceK_Nh/view?usp=sharing

Any help on this regards is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the .xlsx file that you are using, as well as the error message.  Otherwise, it is very difficult to figure out how to help you.

Comment: I have added both the requested data. Kindly have a look whenever you have some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"TypeError: “worksheet” object not callable"
```

tells you, that the variable you are treating like a function is not a function.

In this line

```
ws(row =i+13,col = 'A')#.value = variable_name[i]
```

you are calling `ws` as a function but it is a worksheet. Worksheets are not callable.

According to the documentation here [openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) you can do `ws['A2']` to access cell `A2`. Or in your case `ws['f"A{i+13}"'].value`.

*(Don't know which version you are using. Assumed latest stable 3.0.6. )*